# How to parse the json response of backbone js in the backbone view?

Tags: json, backbone.js, backbone-views

How to parse the response JSON returned from the RESTfull service for the Backbone js

> fetch()

I get the JSON is in the following format.

```
 [{"custId":7,"cookieNum":"","emailId":"raju.allen1888@gmail.com","facebookId":"","twitterId":"","gmailId":"","mobilePhone":""},{"custId":8,"cookieNum":"","emailId":"raju@gmail.com","facebookId":"","twitterId":"","gmailId":"","mobilePhone":""}]
```

but when i print the response in the console

```
   Object { custId=7, tenantId=1, emailId="raju.allen1888@gmail.com", more...}
```

how to parse the response to take the "custId" and "emailId" from the response json in backbone.js

since i'm new to backbone i couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet does the job for me.

```
   this.getSegment = new CustomerCollection();
    this.getSegment.fetch({
          success: function(response) {
              var data = response.toJSON();
              console.log(data[0].custId);
          }
    });
```

i looped it to the length of the json to get custId of all the JSON.

Comment: How do you access the value of data outside success and fetch ?

Answer (score 3):

```
parse: function(response, xhr) {
    return {
        "custId": response.custId,
        "emailId": response.emailId
    }
}
```

fetch() uses parse(). Override parse to use selected data.